# Postgres - 2 database mirror

Tags: postgresql, mirroring

I have 1 DB called - DB_A. I would like to create read only database DB_B from DB_A which updates itself every 10 mins. Is their any easy way to do it in postgres? I am using Postgres 11. Also any data deleted from DB_A should get removed from DB_B on next update.

Comment: [Streaming replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the [recovery_min_apply_delay](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/standby-settings.html) option of streaming replication.

This will give you a rolling 10 minute window, not a leaping window.